# Swift NSBundle pathForResource() returns nil

Tags: swift, uiimage, ios8.3

I have images in my project (which is only supported on iPhones, no iPads). The images are under a group and not under `images.xcassets`.

I want to use the same image for all iPhones, except the @3x for the 6 Plus, so I have a structure as follows:

```
  Project   
        |_ Images_Group
            |
            |_ pic01@2x.png
            |_ pic01@3x.png
```

I am using this code to use it in my app:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pic01", ofType: "png") {
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
```

But `path` always returns nil. Do I need to have `pic01.png`?

The image is present under **Project** > **Build Phases** > **Copy Bundle Resources**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you want here is `UIImage(named:)`, which will look up images the way you're suggesting. `pathForResource` is a generic function that doesn't have special rules for images. It's looking specifically for `pic01.png`, which does not exist.

Comment: I see. Somehow I missed that. I don't want the image cached, hence I was using `pathForResource`. I guess there is no way to work around it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you point to the developer documentation where this is laid out?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Comment: If you don't want it cached, you'll have to construct the path name by hand using the scale. I'm not aware of any method that will return the scale-specific path (which is slightly surprising, but true to the best of my knowledge).