# Get Bundle reference from Path in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filepath, nsbundle

I want to get NSBundle reference from Path in swift.

Like in Objective-c >

```
NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
```

How we can achieve same in swift .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can do that in swift:

```
let languageBundle = NSBundle(path: path)
```

Comment: but its returning nil for me .

Comment: i want to fetch one string file from bundle for localization purpose .

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293861/swift-nsbundle-pathforresource-returns-nil

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle()//path until your project name.app

 var pathForFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Filename", ofType: "db")// path of your file in bundle
```

Swift 4:

```
var pathForFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Filename", ofType: "db")
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3:

```
let bundleFromPath = Bundle(path: path)
```

To load a list of files from the bundle:

```
let docPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/" + bundleName + ".bundle"
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let filesFromBundle = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docPath)
    print(filesFromBundle)
} catch {}
```